# Why doesn't the limit of `h` of the derivative formula approach x?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

For the following graph:

[image: The graph]

We derive an equation to find the derivative (or the slope at an instant point, `x`) which is given by:

[image: The Equation]

However, we are not supposed to find the tangent for the point `x + h` as it approaches `0`. We have to find it as it approaches `x` for *that* will give the tangent at that point of the curve. So, why does the limit of h approach 0 (`lim h->0`) instead of `x` (`lim h->x`)?

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for information on how to format math on this site.

Comment: As $h$ tends to $0$, $x+h$ tends to $x$. You could also write it $f'(x)=\lim_{y\to x}\dfrac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}$ $-$ it comes to the same thing.

Comment: @Regret Thank You! :)

Comment: Uh...why the downvote?

Comment: The downvote was probably from someone not happy with your math formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $x+h\to x\implies (x+h)-x\to0\implies h\to0$. Does that make you understand now?

Answer (score 1):

If you simply plug $\color{blue}{h}=x$ in $f(x+\color{blue}{h})$, you get $f(x+\color{blue}{x}) = f(2x)$ which is not $f(x)$.

If you simply plug $\color{blue}{h}=0$ in $f(x+\color{blue}{h})$, you get $f(x+\color{blue}{0}) = f(x)$.

That should convince us somewhat that we should let $\color{blue}{h}\to 0$ and not $\color{blue}{h}\to x$